# How to substitute a character or expression for a newline using sed?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, tr

How can I substitute a character or expression for a newline using the Unix `sed` command?

(For character substitution, I'd normally use `tr ';' "\n"` command.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Substitute `;` character (semicolon) for a newline using Sed:

   ```
   sed "s/;/\\
   /g"
   ```

   or

   ```
   sed "s/;/\\$(echo -e '\n')/g"
   ```
2. Substitute `[^A-Za-z]` expression (anything but alphabetic characters) for a newline using Sed:

   ```
   sed "s/[^A-Za-z]/\\
   /g"
   ```

   or

   ```
   sed "s/[^A-Za-z]/\\$(echo -e '\n')/g"
   ```

Comment: how about keeping it simple? `sed 's/;/\n/g' <<< "a;b;c;d;e"`

Comment: Isn't the line ending normally `\r\n` rather than `\n\r`?  It certainly is on Windows/DOS; on Unix, of course, it is just `\n`.

Comment: @Vojtech maybe you are running on windows like jonathan pointed out. If its the case im sorry I can't test it on a windows environment, but it works fine under linux.

Comment: @Jonathan-leffler you're right, it's typo. Should have been `\r\n` for compatibility w/ Windows or simply `\n`. I'm running Linux and Mac OS X, btw.

@Lynch correct, `sed 's/;/\n/g'` runs OK on Linux Sed 4.2.1 but doesn't work on BSD Sed.

Comment: With `bash` on Mac OS X, you can use [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) and `sed $'s/;/\\\n/g'` to replace the semicolon with a newline.  The double backslash generates a backslash that escapes the following newline.  You could also split the argument over two lines — but that's hard to show in a comment.  (Tested on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks with the BSD `sed`.)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sed $'s/;/\\\n/g' inputFile
```

```
$ cat inputFile
this;is;a;text
$ sed $'s/;/\\\n/g' inputFile
this
is
a
text
```

Answer (score 1):

a backslash before a literal newline is the portable way to get a newline in sed:

```
$ echo "a,b" | sed 's/,/\
/'
a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed 'y/;/\n/' file
```

or

```
sed $'y/;/\\n/' file
```

or very convolutedly:

```
sed -e 'G' -e ':a' -e 's/\(;\)\(.*\(.\)\)/\3\2/' -e 'ta' -e 's/.$//' file
```